# Multi line CommandButton in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, css

How would you format the following such that the button displayed on two lines?

```
<apex:commandButton value="First line \n Second line">
```

Comment: Dont know apex:command work or not but you can try this `<button type="submit">My<br />Button</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to play around with the CSS to achieve this. You would need to use the `width, word-wrap` properties and add/remove spaces depending upon the word you want to fit in the button.

Below is what i tried in my developer org and achieved the result you expected.

```
<apex:commandButton value="  First line  Second line" style="width: 70px; word-wrap: break-word;"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think apex does not support this. You have one workaround that use

```
 <button OnClick="myFun();">multiline<br/>button<br/>text</button>
 <script>
   function myFun(){
        //alert('hi');
        //CALL YOUR ACTION FUNCTION HERE 
   }
 </script>
```